# Getters/Setters with std::vector<>.push_back(...)

Tags: c++, vector, std

For some reason this doesn't work. It compiles file, but no items are added to this vector when using a getter.

E.G.

```
class class_name {

    public:
        inline std::vector<int> get_numbers() { return m_numbers; }    

    private:
        std::vector<int> m_numbers;
}

....

{
    class_name number_list;
    number_list.get_numbers().push_back(1);
}
```

If I do it directly (m_numbers.push_back(1)) it works, but if I pull it out with a getter it won't add anything.

Comment: Member functions defined inside the class are already implicitly inlined, so the `inline` keyword is not needed (although some people may have other reasons for putting it there).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Return the vector by reference if you plan to modify it:

```
inline std::vector<int> &get_numbers() { return m_numbers; }  
                        ^
```

Without the ampersand a *copy* is returned.